# Notifications installed via Broadcastreceiver are not received

Tags: java, android, push-notification, broadcastreceiver

In my nutrition application, notifications should come reminding the user about the need to eat 4 times a day. The first time you log in to the app (login or register screen) I am registering notifications. However, they either don't come, or they come at a random hour. I tried to write the same code in Mainactivity, but the result is the same

I tried to monitor notifications. I attributed them to come to 13:00, 13:01, 13:02. They either don't come, or only one of them comes. I can't understand what it depends on.

```
`public class LoginOrSignupFragment extends Fragment {

   FragmentLoginOrSignupBinding binding;
   UserViewModel userViewModel;
   NavHostFragment navHostFragment;
   NavController navController;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentLoginOrSignupBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);

         navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainerView);
         navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();

        userViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(getActivity()).get(UserViewModel.class);

        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        binding.logInBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                navController.navigate(R.id.action_loginOrSignupFragment_to_logInFragment);
            }
        });

        binding.signUpBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                navController.navigate(R.id.action_loginOrSignupFragment_to_signUpFragment);
            }
        });


        createNotificationChannel();
        Intent intentBreakfast = new Intent(getContext(), NotificationReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntentBreakfast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 0, intentBreakfast, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Intent intentLunch = new Intent(getContext(), NotificationReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntentLunch = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 1, intentLunch, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Intent intentSnack = new Intent(getContext(), NotificationReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntentSnack = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 2, intentSnack, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Intent intentDinner = new Intent(getContext(), NotificationReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntentDinner= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 3, intentDinner, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) requireContext().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 13);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntentBreakfast);

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 13);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntentLunch);

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 13);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 2);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntentSnack);

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntentDinner);
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel(){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("notifyChannel", "Channel Name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            NotificationManager notificationManager = requireContext().getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }
}`
```

```
`public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // Отправляем уведомление
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "notifyChannel")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                .setContentTitle("Напоминание")
                .setContentText("Время поесть!")
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
        notificationManager.notify(200, builder.build());
    }

}`
```